# Changing Meteor schema validations at different stages of object lifecycle?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I'm making a complex form for a shopping cart and I want to validate different parts of my `order` object at different stages of the order process.

```
OrderSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  itemsOrdered: {
    type: [Object],
    optional: false,
  },
  totalPrice: {
    type: Number,
    optional: false,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    optional: false
  },
  termsAgreed: {
    type: Boolean,
    optional: false
  },
  customerAddress: {
    type: Object,
    optional: false
  },
  stripePaymentInfo: {
    type: Object,
    optional: true,
    blackbox: true
  },
});
```

It's kind of a mess IMO because the different fields need to be validated differently at different stages of the `order`'s life cycle.

- a user still in the middle of selecting products doesn't yet have `termsAgreed`, `customerAddress`, or `stripePaymentInfo` but I don't want validation to fail because of these two since it's still too early in the ordering process to be validating this
- a user filling out their customer address doesn't need `stripePaymentInfo` yet or `termsAgreed`.
- etc

I need the schema to validate successfully at different stages to trigger things like enabling `continue` buttons.

The problem is that `autoform` always wants to use the entire schema to validate the entire object, which is fine for simple objects like Contact Me forms and such that don't have much of a lifecycle.

Is there a best practice or pattern for complex object validation at different stages of their life cycles?

Comment: Mind trying to splitting it into sub-schemas and make a selection from them to combine with to derive different schemas? Or instead extract from it differently at the stages.

Comment: How would you use `autoform` to invoke these sub-schemas at different times?

Comment: You're free to EJSON clone a schema and just tweak the options locally on the client and pass that to the `schema` of your `AutoForm` as well. That's what I do a lot. Beats defining a whole new giant schema just for some small change in form's functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I think the cleanest would be to have one schema with custom validation that validates based on the "state" of the thing in questions, in this case the `Order`.  The "state" could be determined on something that's pre-existing, if you can identify something there already, or by some "state value" you place in your `Order`, like an enumeration or something.  This way your validation is using out-of-the-box SimpleSchema functionality, and you are not tied to any one-off solution that might break functionality downstream.

You would then write a [custom validation function](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#custom-validation) that would look at the state and either do the validation if the state calls for it, or simply returns that the validation is good to let it pass through correctly without validation errors.

Comment: Agree, this calls for custom validation. A (messy) alternative would be to use temporary collections for in-progress orders and then combine the temporary documents into the master collection at the end where the rules would be unambiguous.

Comment: I see. Are there any established patterns or best practices for doing this? I would expect this to be used all the time in form wizards as each step of the wizard gets validated. I can see custom validating becoming a mess as well because validation for a single value could change based on a number of different states. My feeling is that `autoform` is just too tightly-coupled with *one* schema. It would be nice to swap schemas in and out of a single autoform as the user works through the form.

Comment: The alternative for a form wizard would be to have each page represented by a separate schema.  You would then have some unifying ID/object that links them together.  For the most part, form wizard data is usually segregated into "like data" anyhow, with elements on the page being somewhat related (Address/Phone on one page, health info on another, etc).  As far as patterns go, I don't think there is anything set in stone.  I think it comes down to what you feel most comfortable supporting as a developer.