# Best practice for Meteor AutoForm validation of items not in the form?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

`AutoForm` works great when you want to validate a form using the schema, but oftentimes the form doesn't contain all the data that's in the schema, so you get a validation error.

For example, I have a `submit` button that is disabled until it determines the form is completely valid, but because the form doesn't contain all the data that's in the schema, it can never show that it's completely valid.

Say that you've got a schema

```
ShoppingCartSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  itemsOrdered: {
    type: [Object],
    optional: false,
  },
  totalPrice: {
    type: Number,
    optional: false,
  },
  customerAddress: {
    type: Object,
    optional: false
  },
  systemGeneratedInfo: {
    type: Object,
    optional: true,
    blackbox: true
  },
});

ShoppingCarts.attachSchema(ShoppingCartSchema);
```

My form code would be something like:

`{{> quickForm collection="ShoppingCarts" id="shoppingCartForm" type="insert"}}`

Obviously you don't want `totalPrice` to be an item on the form for the user to fill on their own. `systemGeneratedInfo` could be an object that your code generates based on the form values, but which doesn't appear on the form itself.

You could put `totalPrice` into a hidden form element but that seems sketchy. You really wouldn't want to do that with `systemGeneratedInfo`.

What other strategies would there be for tackling items on the object that don't show up on the form, but which still allow the form shown on the front end to be completely validated?

Comment: This seems similar to [this posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558313/changing-meteor-schema-validations-at-different-stages-of-object-lifecycle/38570176#38570176).  Maybe you could take a similar approach?

Comment: No, it's a bit different. This question is about autoform in general - how to validate the form that the user sees when the form itself doesn't contain all the data that the object being validated needs to have.

Comment: Well, I would beg to differ on the likeness between the questions.  But, to answer you bluntly, I don't know of any way in Autoform to simply say "validate only one part of this form, and ignore the rest".  The only ways I can think of, which were touched on in the answer to the other question, would be to either have some state flag in the schema that you could use in your custom validation to either turn on/off validation for a given field, or break out the stuff in the form into a separate schema so it only validates the form values by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of the `schema` field of the `quickForm` or `autoForm`. Then you create Template helpers to pass the schema to the form (or if your schemas are available globally you can just pass `Schemas.someSchema` to the form).

You can either define *completely* new schemas just for minor form functionality tweaks, which in my mind is overkill if you have a giant nested schema and you just want to omit a couple of fields *or...*

You can just import the original schema into your `template.js` and then do an `EJSON.clone` on it and modify the fields and attributes locally in the helper (or elsewhere) before you pass it to the template.

```
//  Profile.js

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { AutoForm } from 'meteor/aldeed:autoform';
import { EJSON } from 'meteor/ejson';

import { Schema } from '../../../api/profiles/profiles.js';

Template.profile.helpers({

  profileSchema: function() {
    let userSchemaForAutoForm = EJSON.clone(Schema.User);
    userSchemaForAutoForm._schema.emails.optional = true;
    return userSchemaForAutoForm;
  }
});
```

```
//  Profile.html

{{#autoForm id="profileEditForm" collection="Meteor.users" schema=profileSchema doc=currentUser type="update"}}
```